# Execute code in activity only call comes from particular activity from a series of calling activities

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I have 3 activities in my app.

`MainActivity`, `SecondActivity` and `ThirdAtivity`. The `MainActivity` and `ThirdActivity` has button each which refer me to `SecondActivity`. I want to execute some code when `SecondActivity` is started only when user moves to that activity from `MainActivity`, but not when from `ThirdAtivity`.

How to do that?

Comment: copy your code on  onResume method .

Comment: pass a flag from MainActivity when calling the SecondActivity. Look for the flag in `onResume` of SecondActivity. If present, do the task else don't.

Comment: @Himani, of what Activity?

Comment: on SecondActivity

Comment: @PrerakSola, how to do that? I never worked with flags before.

Comment: By flag I mean a variable in the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Intents`. Something like this.

```
class Activity1
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("who","Activity1");
startActivity(intent);

class Activity3
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("who","Activity3");
startActivity(intent);

class Activity2
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String whoCalledMe = intent.getStringExtra("who");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in your FirstActivity.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplictionContect, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("code", 1);
                startActivity(intent);
```

In your ThirdActvity.java

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplictionContect, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("code", 2);
                startActivity(intent);
```

In your SecondActivity.java

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
    int code = intent.getIntExtra("code", 0);

 if(code == 1)
 { 
    // Your code
 }
 else
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write that code in `onCreate()` of `SecondActivity.java`

**Edit** 
I didn't realize you can have ThirdActivity as your main launcher activity to. In that case, just pass some flag as others suggested. Like this

In **MainActivity.java**

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class).putExtra("flag", 1));
```

**In ThirdActivty.java**

```
startActivity(new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, SecondActivity.class).putExtra("flag", 3));
```

**In SecondActivity.java**
in onCreate():

```
int flag = getIntent().getIntExtra("flag", -1);
//if flag is 1 coming from MainActivity, if 3 coming from third activity
```

Comment: You said you want to execute some code when coming from MainActivity to SecondActivity. onCreate of SecondActivity will only be called when coming from MainActivity and not from ThirdActivity

Comment: OK. But what if I come to that activity from ThirdActivity?

Comment: And why will it not be executed while coming from third activity?

Comment: When you go from MainActivity to SecondActivity its onCreate will be called and going from second to third, its onpause. But coming back to second from third will only run its onresume. read more about activity lifecycle from the documentation

Comment: But if you have the code where you come from Third to Second, with ThirdActivity being your main launcher activity, this wont work

Answer (score 0):

Use Bundles to set key value pairs when starting SecondActivity from first activity like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("passed_from", "one");
startActivity(intent);
```

and in **SecondActivity**

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b = getIntent().getExtras();
String passed_from= b.getString("passed_from");
```

if passed_from is equal to "one" than run the code

Answer (score 0):

**In the first activity button click:**

```
Intent i=new Intent(First.this,Second.class);
i.putExtra("from","first");
startActivity(i);
```

**In the third activity button click:**

```
Intent i=new Intent(Third.this,Second.class);
i.putExtra("from","third");
startActivity(i);
```

In the second activity receive the intent and check **from where it is coming(which activity button is clicked)** and then write your code accordingly:

**SecondActivity.java**

```
  String from=getIntent().getExtras().getString("from");
    if(from.equals("first"))
    {
       //Button of first activity is clicked
      //Execute your code
    }
```